# move/reflect/reference class to/in another method

Tags: c#, class, e-commerce, checkout

```
public class OrderCard
{

    public string cardnumber { get; set; }
    public string cardname { get; set; }
    public string cardexpire { get; set; }
..
..
}

public class Order
{
    public static Order GetOrder()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart-Order"] != null)
            return (Order)HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart-Order"];
        else
            return new Order();
    }

    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string billingName { get; set; }
    public string billingAddress { get; set; }

    public OrderCard Card { get; set; }

    public bool IsNewCustomer { get; set; }
...
}
```

I created some class like above for checkout process
and I sent/post page information via ajax and json (for to fill **Order** class)

**question #1:** Is it right, to send cOrder to actionPayment() then taking back ?

**question #2:** Is this a true approach (creating class for user's billing information, shopping card information, card information) and transferring it to **Session** then doing/modifying this class information in his all page session for an ecommerce website ?

*****sorry for my english, hope I can explain it*****

```
***** checkout.aspx *****

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static string SaveBillingAndPay(Order cOrder)
{

    OrderCard cardContainer = cOrder.Card;
    ..
    ..
    cOrder = null;
    cOrder = Order.GetOrder();
    cOrder.Card = cardContainer;

    cOrder = actionPayment(cOrder);

    ..
    ..
    return "thanks.aspx";
}

private Order actionPayment(Order cOrder)
{
    // do things

    return cOrder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Question #1:** Is it right, to send cOrder to actionPayment() then taking back ?

**Answer 1:** Yes, This is entirely valid approach of processing order. In e-commerce applications, entire order details are getting stored in one single entity. Remember, it is an object of a class you are passing, it will be passed via a copy of its memory reference location. Entire object is not getting copied into parameter all the time unless you are passing it over the network. You are passing in an object, it has some action executed, few more fields populated back, and then you get the object back with more details.

**Question #2:** Is this a true approach (creating class for user's billing information, shopping card information, card information) and transferring it to Session then doing/modifying this class information in his all page session for an ecommerce website ?

**Answer 2:** It depends. Where is the session stored? Mostly in e-commerce applications, session is stored in databases like SQL server. It may look bad but it facilitates something. If user wants to leave his session mid-way and return tomorrow to complete the order, he will get his last loaded session back. With this, he will have its entire product selection back into cart(s). He will have non-committed order details back on order screen and basically, he can continue from where he left off. Once order is completed and payment is made, these details must be getting converted to order and removed from session. If your application is storing this session detail completely and only in memory, you are doing something incorrect. **Also, do not store credit card or payment or bank account details of the user in plain text or otherwise in database, by yourself, unless user wants to save it for later transactions. Also, in these  cases, PIN or CVV numbers or expiry date should not be stored. Only store transaction id provide by the payment gateway, so that the transaction can be mapped back in case of issues, and at the most, last 4 digits, if your transaction policies allow.**